# New mailbox added but only administrator visible

Tags: exchange, mailbox

I have Exchange 2007 configured seemingly properly, I could use the outlook with default administrator fine, but when I created a new mailbox by going through wizard only administrator visible, any ideas?

Thansk,

Comment: Please ignore this, I overlooked the warning when finish creating the mailbox, password too weak.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To share my experience, make sure the exchange server is communicating property with Active Directory as the list of users are obtained from AD.